# Adding area gradient to line highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to add an area gradient to my highchart similar to an area or an areaspline chart. Unfortunately I can't use those as they tend to make my chart seem uninteresting since my data usually changes between a difference of around 3. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/gabedesigns/pen/GXZPqg?editors=1111 and here is some example code:

```
    $('#Platinum').highcharts('StockChart', {
    colors: ['#E48701'],
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: true
    },
   yAxis: {
      labels: {
        format: '${value:,.0f}'
              },
    title: {
      text: 'Platinum'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Price',
      data: [787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 787, 787, 786, 786, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 786, 786, 787, 787, 787, 788, 787, 787, 788, 788, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 788, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 787, 786, 786, 786, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 786, 785, 785, 785, 785, 784, 785, 785, 784, 785, 784, 784, 784, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 784],
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 0
      }
    }]
  });
```

I've taken a look at the various examples on here and on the documentation, but the charts are all either area, areaspline, or spline charts. Mine has to be line type chart otherwise things start looking very boring.

Edit:
I was unclear of what I am trying to achieve. Basically I want the same gradient effect under the line just like how an area chart has, but sadly I can't use an area, spline, or areaspline chart since they both curve the line and makes the chart kinda boring in my opinion. Hopefully this clears up some stuff.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have the line be gradient colored?

Comment: do you have a picture of what you expect? Is it the line itself, which should be in gradient colors or the area under the line?

Comment: @toffler I don't sadly, but underneath the line just like a area chart

Comment: @ewolden sorry for the miscommunication I mean under the line

Comment: @G-Cyr I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Hopefully my other comments clear up any miscommunications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the type `area` under the condition that you set `threshold: null` ... This works even for a data-range of 3.
Below is an example of an area highchart with your data.

```js
// create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    title: {
      text: 'Platinum'
    },

    xAxis: {
      gapGridLineWidth: 0
    },

  rangeSelector : {
      buttons: [
        {
        type: 'all',
        count: 1,
        text: 'All'
        }
      ],
      selected: 1,
      inputEnabled: false
  },

    series: [{
      name: 'Price',
      type: 'area',
      data: [787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 787, 787, 786, 786, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 786, 786, 787, 787, 787, 788, 787, 787, 788, 788, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 788, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787, 786, 787, 786, 786, 786, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 786, 785, 785, 785, 785, 784, 785, 785, 784, 785, 784, 784, 784, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 785, 784],
      gapSize: 5,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      },
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          y1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
          [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
      },
      threshold: null
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!